# Trigger Dataflow(Python SDK) Job using cloud-functions

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a requirement to process incoming csv files in gcs.

I am not able to trigger execution by shell commands in cloud-functions like:

```
subprocess.run([
    "python", "-W", "ignore", "dataflow_ingestion_engine.py",
    "gs://logs-check/csv_input/input2.csv", "--runner", "DataflowRunner"]
    )
```

### or

```
command = """
python tmp/dataflow_ingestion_engine.py gs://logs-check/csv_input/input2.csv --runner DataflowRunner
"""
os.system(command)
```

Cloud-function is not execution the shell execution part(Not seeing anything in the log). 
How to achieve the requirement of triggering dataflow(Python-SDK) using cloud-function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot invoke dataflow jobs from Cloud Functions using a sub-process command. You will have to make REST or gRPC calls from your cloud function code.

A sample job to run templates can be found here [1].

You can refer to this and submit your own job.

1 - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/dataflow/run_template

Comment: Can you share some tutorial on creating template?

Comment: You can take a look at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates. Also, in the dataflow job page there are multiple templates already available. All those templates can be found here - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates. If this answer helped please do accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the google tutorial for creating templates is not that great.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, in the tutorial at the end there is a link to provide feedback. It would be great if you can provide your feedback so that we can improve upon your suggestion.